# Linearity of expectation of an infinite series of random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

$(Z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are random variables such that $\mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{i=1}^\infty |Z_i| \right) < \infty$. Show that $\mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{i=1}^\infty Z_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}(Z_i)$.

It seems like the result should follow from linearity of expectation, but I assume the key is checking that the sequence $\sum_{i=1}^\infty Z_i$ converges. $$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty Z_i \leq  \sum_{i=1}^\infty |Z_i|$$ so I feel like $$ \mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{i=1}^\infty Z_i \right)\leq \mathbb{E} \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty |Z_i|\right) < \infty$$ but is this correct? And if so, would it imply that $\mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{i=1}^\infty |Z_i| \right) < \infty$ converges?

Comment: That's all correct.

Comment: No, linearity is only for a finite number of terms, you can't immediately generalize it to infinite sums. The statement follows from the dominated convergence theorem from measure theory. Are you familiar with it?

Comment: @Mark ah, its the next theorem in my notes. Seems like I jumped into the exercise too soon. Thanks.

Comment: Besides, in your approach it seems like you are trying to use comparison tests for series which don't have nonnegative terms, which you also can't do.